# How to pick color in consecutive manner using function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to pick color in consecutive manner using function in React?

This is my functionwhich return a random colour how can i modify in such a way that it should pick one colour then when function runs it picks next to that  colur

```
    const randomColor = () => {
        const arrayColour = ["#C5D374", "#EECB52", "#F7F7F7", "#A6CDF2", "#F47869", "#F05050", "#27C24C"]
        return arrayColour[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayColour.length)];
    };
```

utilizing this function in main jsx return function

```
const NumberFormate = () => {
        return(
          <div claassName = "Main">
            states.numbers.map(num=> (
                <div key = {num.key}>
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: randomColor() }}>
                        <p ><span> {num.important} </span></p>              
                    </div>
           </div>
)}
```

This is working fine but right now i am generating random color but how can we pick one by one color in sequence in consecutive manner and if the array ends it should start with beginning again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *modulo* - `i % arrayColour.length`.

```js
const arrayColour = ["#C5D374", "#EECB52", "#F7F7F7", "#A6CDF2", "#F47869", "#F05050", "#27C24C"]

const randomColor = () => {
  return arrayColour[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayColour.length)];
};

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   console.log(arrayColour[i % arrayColour.length]);
}
```

In your particular case:

```
states.numbers.map((num, i) => (
    <div key={num.key}>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: arrayColour[i % arrayColour.length] }}>
             <p><span> {num.important} </span></p>              
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure to achieve this. Remembering and operating on the index of the previous color.

```js
const nextColorFactory = (colors = [], index = -1) => () => {
  if (++index > colors.length - 1) index = 0
  return colors[index] || 'no colors provided'
}

const nextColor = nextColorFactory([
  "#C5D374", "#EECB52", "#F7F7F7", "#A6CDF2", "#F47869", "#F05050", "#27C24C"
])

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  console.log(nextColor())
}
```